# Python Mechanize problems with form finding

Tags: python, forms, find, mechanize-python

I have been trying to make a program with Mechanize to comment on "https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/138659469/" but it hasn't been working and I don't know why. 
I don't know which form number it is, and it doesn't have a name, so I was trying to use the `try:`  and `except:` in order to try all the forms in order to get to the one I wanted.

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/138659469/")
for i in range(500):
    try:
        br.select_form(nr=i)
        br.form['content'] = 'Nice'
        req = br.submit()
    except:
        pass
```

Can you help me determine what is going wrong?
Any help to fix this or any alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not do an `inspect` or `view page source` (in a browser) on the object you wish to manipulate?

Comment: I can, but I would like to use this shell for multiple places. I would prefer a way that allows me to not have to search through the page source every time. If all else fails, I will do it by searching, but I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, I think that the program is working. The website is blocking it though.